# Menu does not set active trail when generating tree in theme file

Tags: theming, 8, navigation

I want to display the whole menu tree in my Drupal 8 theme to be able to show/hide submenus using javascript. To accomplish that, I added the following code to my theme file:

```
function pspartner_preprocess_page(&$variables) {

  $menu_tree = \Drupal::menuTree();
  $menu_name = 'main';

  // Build the typical default set of menu tree parameters.
  $parameters = new MenuTreeParameters();

  // Load the tree based on this set of parameters.
  $tree = $menu_tree->load($menu_name, $parameters);

  // Transform the tree using the manipulators you want.
  $manipulators = array(
    // Only show links that are accessible for the current user.
    array('callable' => 'menu.default_tree_manipulators:checkAccess'),
    // Use the default sorting of menu links.
    array('callable' => 'menu.default_tree_manipulators:generateIndexAndSort'),
  );
  $tree = $menu_tree->transform($tree, $manipulators);

  // Finally, build a renderable array from the transformed tree.
  $menu = $menu_tree->build($tree);

  // Make menus available in templates
  $variables['main_menu_tree'] = $tree;
  $variables['main_menu'] = $menu;
}
```

This works, but the active trail is not set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the active trail in the MenuTreeParameter object per [MenuTreeParameters::setActivityTrail](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Menu!MenuTreeParameters.php/function/MenuTreeParameters%3A%3AsetActiveTrail/8). This requires knowing the menu link plugin ids, which can be retrieved using [MenuActiveTrail::GetActiveTrailIds](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Menu!MenuActiveTrail.php/function/MenuActiveTrail%3A%3AgetActiveTrailIds/8) (linked from the previous API page).

```
  $active_trail = \Drupal::service('menu.active_trail');

  // Build the typical default set of menu tree parameters.
  $parameters = new MenuTreeParameters();
  $parameters->setActiveTrail($active_trail->getActiveTrailIds($menu_name));
```